# Can't change view from WatchKit controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I added a bunch of WKInterfaceLabels to the storyboard, added them as IBOutlets in InterfaceController.h, and used the SetText method to set some text on them.  However, I get no change on the view.  The console gives the message "Unknown property in Interface description" for each label.  How do I fix this?

In InterfaceController.h, I define the label as follows:

```
IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *hdate;
```

In InterfaceController.m, I set it's text as follows:

```
- (void)willActivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
[super willActivate];
[hdate setText:@"blah"];}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Pasted my code in the OP.

Comment: Are you sure that your IBOutlets are actually connected in interface builder?

Comment: try setting your text in `- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context` instead

Comment: I'm sure the outlets are connected in IB (the filled in dot appears next to them in the code as well).  I also tried setting the text in awakeWithContext to no avail.  Doing a google search of the message in the console only brings up this post.

Comment: Is the correct class selected in interface builder? Honestly, running out of options without seeing more code (or ideally, a small project).

Comment: I figured it out.  I can't create the IBOutlet in the .h file with just IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *hdate in brackets, I have to set them as properties.

Comment: Very true. I missed that you hadn't defined it as a property. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Since the correct answer is in the comments of the question, I will just post it here again:

You can't create the IBOutlet in the .h file with just

```
IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *hdate
```

in brackets, I have to set them as properties.

(Credits to user3261697)

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
IBOutlet
```

To

```
@IBOutlet
```

Or reconnect the label to the view.

In my case, it ran successfully.